# What type of application to subscribe to Azure Message Queues?

Tags: azure, message

We are currently using Azure more like IAAS, rather than cloud services.

As a start, I would like to utilise Azure Messaging Queues to process some database actions and Web API calls.

I am assuming I would need to write another piece of code that subscribes to the queues, so when messages arrive, it knows to process the transaction?

Is that piece of code, a console app? runs on a scheduled task? a windows service? or a function app within azure?

What is the Best Practice for this architecture?

Answer (score 0):

You can write console app and schedule web job to monitor the queue. However better way is to use Azure Functions. You don't have to monitor the queue then. Whenever the message arrives in the queue it will trigger Azure Function and you can process the message. The benefit is it's server-less.

Comment: For instance, if i have microservice creating a Message in the Queue for microservice2 to pick up. but Microservice2 needs to pass the ID back to microservice after it has completed the transaction. Does it simply chuck the Message back into the Queue? How does Microservice know that Microservice2 has completed part A?

Comment: That's right, This is called Async communication(AMQP). Once MicroService1 (MS1) drops the message in Queue it shouldn't care what happens to the message and that's the whole point creating loosely coupled Microservices. So there is not way For MS1 to know that message has been processed. MS2 will have to drop the message in another queue  for MS1 to pick that up once completed and that's how MS1 would know the transaction is completed. The pattern itself is called Saga and you can find more about here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YPbGW3Fnmbc&index=5&list=LLxfaEBq0Fa7eiKokf98ojxA&t=0s

Comment: you may look into creating topics in queue so you may only use one queue. ms1 send message to one topic for ms2 to pick up and ms2 then send message to different topic that ms1 is subscribed to